# How to drop messages in Akka Streams for downstream if downstream is still working

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I need to drop all incoming messages from upstream to downstream if downstream is still processing the previous message. I've tried to do this by limiting a buffer, but have gotten no success. How can I achieve that?

Here is my simple example

```scala
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Test extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("System")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val (actor, actorSource) = Source.actorRef[Int](bufferSize = 0, OverflowStrategy.dropBuffer).preMaterialize()

  class ActualScheduledActor extends Actor {

    var idx: Int = 0

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case _: Int =>
        idx = idx + 1
        if (idx < 6) {
          println(s"sending $idx")
          actor ! idx
        }
    }
  }

  val flow = Flow[Int].map { v =>
    println(s"$v: Going to sleep.")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println(s"$v: Awake.")
    v
  }

  val scheduledActor = system.actorOf(Props(new ActualScheduledActor))
  system.scheduler.schedule(0.second, 1.second, scheduledActor, 0)

  actorSource
    .buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.dropBuffer)
    .via(flow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
}
```

In this example I use ActualScheduledActor just to demonstrate that messages haven't dropped and seem to be buffered. Here is an output:

```
sending 1
1: Going to sleep.
sending 2
sending 3
sending 4
sending 5
1: Awake.
2: Going to sleep.
2: Awake.
3: Going to sleep.
3: Awake.
4: Going to sleep.
4: Awake.
5: Going to sleep.
5: Awake.
```

Answer (score 0):

It does drop messages, you're just not sending enough of them.

Consider this modified code based on yours.

```scala
object AkkaStreamDropMessage extends App {
  import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
  import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}

  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("System")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val (actor, actorSource) = Source
    .actorRef[Int](bufferSize = 0, OverflowStrategy.dropBuffer)
    .preMaterialize()

  class ActualScheduledActor extends Actor {

    var idx: Int = 0

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case _: Int =>
        idx = idx + 1
        if (idx < 600) {
//          println(s"sending $idx")
          actor ! idx
        }
    }
  }

  val flow = Flow[Int].map { v =>
    println(s"GOT: $v")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    v
  }

  val scheduledActor = system.actorOf(Props(new ActualScheduledActor))
  system.scheduler.schedule(0.second, 50.millis, scheduledActor, 0)

  actorSource
    .buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.dropBuffer)
    .via(flow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
}
```

It eventually stops receiving sequential numbers

```
GOT: 34
GOT: 35
GOT: 36
GOT: 37
GOT: 38
GOT: 39
GOT: 49
```

In my run it dropped about 300 elements out of 600.

I think (but I might be wrong) it's related to additional internal buffers that are defined for each stage and thus it has to fill them up before actual "dropping" is visible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What materializer have you used?

Comment: @SergeyKravchenya same as you did. Added to my code

Comment: So I ran your code and got all messages. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SergeyKravchenya that is strange. I used latest akka libs 2.6.4. Try using those too

Comment: Either way I need the message being dropped not after filling "internal buffers", but when downstream is busy.